# Tag Synonym Suggestion

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

This is not a big deal at all, but I'm a bit OCD, and I don't have the rep to do it myself.

I suggest making [browsers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browsers) a synonym of [web-browser](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser).

Comment: Agreed, that tag really should not have been created - and would have been caught sooner or later... Thats the downside of the low rep-requirement for creating new tags... :( but thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have suggested it here: https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/web-browser/synonyms

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Comment: Thanks, @Karrax. I tried, but I keep forgetting how convoluted the synonym system is.

Comment: Thanks, I mod-approved it :)